# What wallet formats are supported by Bitcoin Core?

Tags: wallet

When issuing the `getwalletinfo` RPC in Bitcoin Core, what are the possible results for the "format" field, and what do they mean?

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by format?

Comment: When put in getwalletinfo, you have wallet name, wallet version, and format, can you tell me what the format should say, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by what it should be. It is what it is. The RPC reports what format your wallet it. It's not a means for detecting problems. The possibilities are "bdb" or "sqlite".

Comment: What is the differance between the two possibilities?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your question to what I think you actually want to know, and answered it. Feel free to comment if this wasn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The "format" field in the `getwalletinfo` RPC output of modern Bitcoin Core releases reports what file format your the respective wallet file is in. The possibilities are:

- "bdb": BerkleleyDB file. This was the only supported format up until release v0.20.x
- "sqlite": SQLite file. This was added as an experimental option in release v0.21.0. It is only used for descriptor wallets, which are a new type of wallet, which won't be created by default.

In short, unless you created a wallet with version v0.21.0 or later, and explicitly chose to create a descriptor wallet, this RPC will report "bdb".

Wallets are created in one format, and stay in that format during lifetime. New Bitcoin Core versions will keep supporting both.

Comment: I have format "bdb cheers.